# Writing the condition x <= y AND x > 0

Tags: c#, lambda

My current condition is written as follows:

```
.Where(m => Math.Round((m.DateAndTime - DateTime.Now).TotalMinutes, 0) <= 30 && Math.Round((m.DateAndTime - DateTime.Now).TotalMinutes, 0) > 0)
```

which basically says where the rounded value is less than or equal to `30` and the rounded value is greater than `0`.

Is there a neater way to write this than having

```
Math.Round((m.DateAndTime - DateTime.Now).TotalMinutes, 0)
```

twice in the same statement?

The full expression is:

```
List<Meeting> finalList = initialList.Where(m => Math.Round((m.DateAndTime - DateTime.Now).TotalMinutes, 0) <= 30 && Math.Round((m.DateAndTime - DateTime.Now).TotalMinutes, 0) > 0).ToList();
```

Comment: I really wanted to comment on all the answers, but I have always found it easier to read

     `0 < value && value <= 30`

in those languages that don't allow you to write

    `0 < value <= 30`

It makes it much clearer that you're testing for something to be in a specified range.

Comment: @TomTanner, a valid point and I'd normally do the same. I kept my order the same as the OP's though to avoid causing possible confusion.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you need to store a result of a method you should just create a method for it.

```
private bool IsInRange(DateTime dateTime, decimal min, decimal max)
{
    decimal totalMinutes = Math.Round((dateTime - DateTime.Now).TotalMinutes, 0);
    return totalMinutes > min && totalMinutes <= max;
}
```

now your expression looks like so

```
.Where(m => IsInRange(m.DateAndTime, 0, 30));
```

but the values `0` and `30` are still magic numbers which should be extracted to meaningful constants.

The choosen method name is not the best like [@Falco](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/46500/falco) has correctly pointed out in his comment

> UhhOhhh Horribly wrong named Function.... AreMinutesInRangeFromNow or something like this would be better - with your Method-Name I would expect no Magic happening with DateTime.Now - or pass the already substracted value, but don't hide this!

so you should change it to a better name.  I don't like the name [@Falco](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/46500/falco) suggested either but couldn't come up with a different one. So it is up to you to choose one.

Comment: Oh, weird, I always get errors like `Method 'Boolean functionName(System.String, System.String)' has no supported translation to SQL.` I figured you just couldn't call functions in linq queries.

Comment: I would expect `min` to come before `max` in the parameter list.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft you are right. Updated answer.

Comment: UhhOhhh Horribly wrong named Function.... `AreMinutesInRangeFromNow` or something like this would be better - with your Method-Name I would expect no Magic happening with `DateTime.Now` - or pass the already substracted value, but don't hide this!

Comment: @crclayton You can call functions in linq queries as long as you're not querying the database itself in your query, otherwise it thinks you're trying to translate things to SQL, so what I do is pull the list from the db, then run linq queries on that list object.

Comment: I'd name it something like `OccursWithinNext` and pass a `TimeSpan` rather than two integers _(this is slightly different, since it assumes `min` is always 0)_

Answer (score 15):

One way is to use query-style LINQ and the `let` keyword:

```
var finalList = (from m in initialList
                 let value = Math.Round((m.DateAndTime - DateTime.Now).TotalMinutes
                 where value <= 30 && value > 0
                 select m).ToList();
```

Comment: Why would you rewrite it to query-style, when the asker clearly prefers method-style?

Comment: @ANeves, why do you assume the OP prefers the fluent style? I use both styles, depending on the requirement. Further, these answers aren't just for the benefit of the OP, but for others who come searching with similar questions. They may prefer the query syntax; or they may not. Having said all that, if the OP doesn't like using query syntax, then Johnbot has a viable alternative solution that sticks to the fluent style.

Comment: I agree that I should not assume *preference*. But it is what he is using in the question; I still think that using query-style distracts from the actual solution.

Comment: @ANeves, is there an equivalent of the `let` keyword in fluent style?

Comment: @ArturoTorresSánchez I'm not sure. R# converts it to something like [the answer from Johnbot](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/97678/7773), but I would declare a block lambda instead of a statement lambda and extract a variable, like in [my answer](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/97683/7773).

Comment: @ArturoTorresSánchez you have to select to a new object (usually an anonymous object or tuple with the first value the original object and the second/subsequent value(s) the calculated value(s)

Comment: @ANeves there's not really an equivalent to this using fluent syntax and the closest way is a bit clunky. As far as function goes, this is the most elegant. Form-wise, it's up to the individual's aesthetic preference.

Comment: @moarboilerplate If you look at the IL from this answer and mine you'll see that they're identical except for the anonymous type and delegate names.

Comment: @moarboilerplate and section 7.16.2.4 of the C# Language Specification Version 5.0: "From, let, where, join and orderby clauses" details this exact translation.

Comment: I actually really like this solution, but it isn't as elegant as the accepted answer which is fluent-style as you guys say. It seems to me that somebody that doesn't mind query-style will be better off using this. Unless there is an equivalent using fluent?

Comment: @Johnbot as far as MSIL goes, sure. As far as a mental model goes, the let keyword is the closest to the functional style (because it gives you the impression you have this standalone variable that's not just a property on a projected object). When working with LINQ I personally focus less on what it compiles down to and more on writing LINQ that keeps the functional mental model consistent (even if what's going on under the hood is not very functional and more of a creative way to call `MoveNext()`). I suppose it's sort of this in-between area in the debate of form vs. function.

Answer (score 10):

Write an [IsBetween extension method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5023279/648075):

```
public static bool IsBetween<T>(this T item, T start, T end)
{
    return Comparer<T>.Default.Compare(item, start) >= 0
        && Comparer<T>.Default.Compare(item, end) <= 0;
}
```

And use it like this:

```
.Where(m => Math.Round((m.DateAndTime - DateTime.Now).TotalMinutes, 0).IsBetween(0, 30))
```

(And also take into account the remarks WRT magic numbers and UtcNow etc.)

Answer (score 8):

## Use a block-lambda and extract a variable

You can use a block-lambda instead of a statement lambda, and extract a variable:

```
var now = DateTime.Now;
List<Meeting> finalList = initialList.Where(m => {
    var minutesToNow = Math.Round((m.DateAndTime - now).TotalMinutes, 0);
    return minutesToNow <= 30 && minutesToNow > 0
}).ToList();
```

Alternatively, use a method like Heslacher [suggested](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/97674/7773).

## Use UtcNow

You should avoid using local times, and use Utc times. Prefer `DateTime.UtcNow` to `DateTime.Now`.

Comment: Good idea on avoiding local times if I ever want my software to scale internationally!

Answer (score 5):

You can introduce an additional `Select` where you calculate the offset from `Now`:

```
var finalList =
    initialList.Select(m =>
                        new
                            {
                                Meeting = m,
                                MinutesOffsetFromNow = Math.Round((m.DateAndTime - DateTime.Now).TotalMinutes, 0)
                            })
                .Where(x => x.MinutesOffsetFromNow <= 30 && x.MinutesOffsetFromNow > 0)
                .Select(x => x.Meeting)
                .ToList();
```

And then transform it back to only a `Meeting` just before the `ToList`.

---

Doing calculations correctly with time is hard using just `DateTime`, especially if you have to consider time zone changing as with daylight saving time or users in different time zones.

You should consider if [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org/) can help you express you intents more clearly.

Answer (score 2):

You can simplify your condition, and not use `Math.Round` (which is really not needed here). It will be more concise and **readable**:

```
dt > DateTime.Now && dt <= DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30)
```

Comment: Oh there's a very important reason I use Math.Round, but that has nothing to do with the question